# App craches when installed from Google Play but not when from Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play, android-volley

i'm developing an app using Volley to make REST API calls. Everything works great during dev time, but now i put it on Google Play and it crashs when i make this calls.

When i generate a signed apk, put this apk in my device and install it works, but when i upload this same apk to Google Play and install from there, any API call crashes the app. Looking server log it doesn't even hit there!

Anyone knows what can possibly be?

Comment: What is the crash?  I'm guessing the difference between running locally versus running what is on the Google Play store is proguard.

Comment: I dont know what crash is. I sent google report, but it doesnt show in Play Console yet. I supose its proguard also, but i'm not sure...

Comment: Maybe its a good idea publish an apk without proguard meanwhile i try to figure out? And if it woks we know for sure that is proguard. What do you think @MichaelKrause?

Comment: Can you download your app from the Google Play store and run it and see if you can get the crash to happen that way?  If so, you can grab the stack trace from logcat and post.

Comment: Actually i don't understand what exactly you told me to do. But for test i've just uploaded a new version to internal testers without proguard and it worked... now i have to figure out whtas going on

Comment: OK.  By the way, here is [a related answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51311153/766755) that might help you in debugging your issue with proguard.